# Formatting 4Kn SSD USB device (physical sector:4096 bytes)

Tags: partition

I don't manage to install last releases of Linux (Debian, Xubuntu,...) on 4Kn SSD USB device: no error during install but can't boot.
It seems that many Linux installers and partition management tools don't support 4Kn format that yet has been existing for more than 12 years !
(no prob to put W11 installer on this SSD USB and boot from it)

I tried to manually make partitions and format them but I get a very strange thing: mkfs makes partitions vanish !

Here is what I've tried from Debian 11.
(Linux debian 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Infos device

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disque /dev/sda : 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Modèle de disque : TS500GSSD220Q  
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0xa2c5981d

Périphérique Amorçage     Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sda1    *             2048 974772223 974770176 464,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2             974774270 976771071   1996802   975M  5 Étendue
/dev/sda5             974774272 976771071   1996800   975M 82 partition d'échange Linux / Solaris


Disque /dev/loop0 : 20 KiB, 20480 octets, 40 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop1 : 118,23 MiB, 123973632 octets, 242136 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop2 : 63,45 MiB, 66535424 octets, 129952 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop3 : 44,27 MiB, 46419968 octets, 90664 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
                                                                                                       
                                                                                                       
Disque /dev/loop4 : 116,76 MiB, 122433536 octets, 239128 secteurs                                      
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets                                                              
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets                                      
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets                                          
                                                                                               
                                                                                                       
Disque /dev/loop5 : 63,45 MiB, 66531328 octets, 129944 secteurs                                        
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets                                                              
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets                                      
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets                                          


Disque /dev/sdb : 238,37 GiB, 255944818688 octets, 62486528 secteurs
Modèle de disque : Tech            
Unités : secteur de 1 × 4096 = 4096 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 268431360 octets
```

/dev/sdb, SSD USB 250GB, is well detected as "4K native", with "Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets" that means size of logical/physical sector = 4096 bytes.

*** Cleaning

```
~$ sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdb
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table
entries is 0 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table
entries is 0 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Creating new GPT entries in memory.
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
```

Strange warnings because previous tests ....

*** GPT partition table creation

```
$ sudo sgdisk -o /dev/sdb
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table
entries is 0 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table
entries is 0 bytes, but this program  supports only 128-byte entries.
Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.
Creating new GPT entries in memory.
The operation has completed successfully.
--------------
```

*** Creation of partitions

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disque /dev/sdb : 238,37 GiB, 255944818688 octets, 62486528 secteurs
Modèle de disque : Tech            
Unités : secteur de 1 × 4096 = 4096 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 268431360 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt
Identifiant de disque : 30D18F46-9F29-4450-BABA-8832CC105AE6

------------------------

$ sudo sgdisk -n 1:1M:+1G -t 1:ef00 -c 1:EFI-0003 /dev/sdb
Setting name!
partNum is 0
The operation has completed successfully.

$ sudo sgdisk -n 2:0:+230G -t 2:8300 -c 2:ARTIX-0003 /dev/sdb
Setting name!
partNum is 1
The operation has completed successfully.

$ sudo partprobe -s
/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1 2 <5>
/dev/sdb: gpt partitions 1 2

-----------
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disque /dev/sdb : 238,37 GiB, 255944818688 octets, 62486528 secteurs
Modèle de disque : Tech            
Unités : secteur de 1 × 4096 = 4096 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 268431360 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : gpt
Identifiant de disque : 30D18F46-9F29-4450-BABA-8832CC105AE6

Périphérique  Début      Fin Secteurs Taille Type
/dev/sdb1       256   262399   262144     1G Système EFI
/dev/sdb2    262400 60555519 60293120   230G Système de fichiers Linux
```

All seems OK ! :)
... but from there, it's getting worse !!!

*** Formatting

```
$ sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 -s 2 -S 4096 -v /dev/sdb
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
mkfs.vfat: Partitions or virtual mappings on device '/dev/sdb', not making filesystem (use -I to override)
```

Because remaining "sh!ts" ?

```
$ sudo mkfs.vfat -I -F32 -s 2 -S 4096 -v /dev/sdb
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Adding MBR table
/dev/sdb has 255 heads and 63 sectors per track,
hidden sectors 0x0000;
logical sector size is 4096,
using 0xf8 media descriptor, with 62486487 sectors;
drive number 0x80;
filesystem has 2 32-bit FATs and 2 sectors per cluster.
FAT size is 30482 sectors, and provides 31212745 clusters.
There are 32 reserved sectors.
Volume ID is 7f449e92, no volume label.

-------------
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -b 4096 -F /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
Creating filesystem with 62486528 4k blocks and 15622144 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 72189b38-a913-467c-ae87-b42820aff572
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

It seems quite good ?...

But NO, it's a drama !

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disque /dev/sdb : 238,37 GiB, 255944818688 octets, 62486528 secteurs
Modèle de disque : Tech            
Unités : secteur de 1 × 4096 = 4096 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 268431360 octets
-------------------
?!? Nothing else ?!?


$ sudo fdisk -l
Disque /dev/sda : 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Modèle de disque : TS500GSSD220Q  
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0xa2c5981d

Périphérique Amorçage     Début       Fin  Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sda1    *             2048 974772223 974770176 464,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2             974774270 976771071   1996802   975M  5 Étendue
/dev/sda5             974774272 976771071   1996800   975M 82 partition d'échange Linux / Solaris


Disque /dev/loop0 : 20 KiB, 20480 octets, 40 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop1 : 118,23 MiB, 123973632 octets, 242136 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop2 : 63,45 MiB, 66535424 octets, 129952 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop3 : 44,27 MiB, 46419968 octets, 90664 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop4 : 116,76 MiB, 122433536 octets, 239128 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop5 : 63,45 MiB, 66531328 octets, 129944 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/sdb : 238,37 GiB, 255944818688 octets, 62486528 secteurs
Modèle de disque : Tech            
Unités : secteur de 1 × 4096 = 4096 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 268431360 octets
```

Partitions on /dev/sdb VANISHED !!!

I don't understand what I missed.
Any idea/suggestion ?

Did you manage to install Linux (what exact distro) on 4Kn SSD USB (or HDD) ? How ?

I can provide any info if needed.

Thanks,

Steph.

Comment: It is clear that you used the mkfs.vfat command to destroy the partition table, despite the clearly readable warning.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Adding to @IporSircer's comment - /dev/sdb is the entire disk, /dev/sdb1 is the first partition, /dev/sdb2 the second, and so on.  Or would be if you hadn't wiped the partition table by formatting the entire disk /dev/sdb with mkfs.vfat.   I recommend re-partitioning the drive and formatting only the partition(s).  And don't use vfat for sdb2 unless you really need it to exchange files between linux and dos/windows, use a linux-native filesystem like ext4 or xfs. The EFI partition , sdb1, pretty much has to be FAT12, 16, or 32 as most BIOSes don't support anything other than that for EFI.